# excluding config file while converting node js files to exe using pkg

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe

I'm developing a node.js application.
To make the application unreadable for users, I'm trying to convert js files to exe.
I'm using pkg to convert my files but got an issue.
pkg module does convert all of my project to exe, but I have a config file in the directory that I don't want it to be converted.

this config files is used to get user's credentials and custom configs and load that in my project.
unfortunately the config file which is written in json will be added to my exe file and cannot be edited after compiling.
I've read the documentation of pkg module but didn't find anything useful.
I'll be thankful If any one can suggest a solution for my problem,or if there is any other solution for protecting the code

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know the exe will include your plaintext code, so this is not a safe way to protect your code. Why not just move the file out of the way during packaging ?

Comment: If I remove the config file while packaging the code, it ends up showing up errors about variables in code that are being used from the config file.

Comment: why not make a copy of it then? @nimasoufiloo

Comment: cause the exe program ignores the copied file and instead uses the config file which is embedded the exe package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found my mistake.
I was requiring the config file in my javascript program which made pkg module to count config files as main program files and then packages them in the exe file.
Instead I had to use read content of the file so the config file doesn't count in my program's files.
Using fs.readFile() solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/195
use fs to read config file insead of require or import
eg:
const configPath = path.join(process.cwd(), './config/config.json');
lset data = fs.readFileSync(configPath);